# Python in Eclipse not working

Tags: python, eclipse

[image: Click here for the image]

This file prank has lots of files. This works perfectly in the Terminal but not in the eclipse.

Comment: You aren't calling that function if you are running this file

Answer (score 0):

Can't understand how it's working in the terminal (can you show what are you running there). Anyway in this code you don't call to your function. The code in the image should do nothing. Add rename_files() before or after the function declaration.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was the PYTHONPATH which was different in the eclipse IDE from the terminal. Just matched them to solve the issue.